# Script to email administrator when a duplicate IP is found on the network

Tags: networking, email, script, dhcp

I know this is a bit of a custom requirement but I was hoping someone currently has (or can put together) a script that checks for duplicate IP addresses on a network (something that might occur when someone assigns their own static IP when that lease has already been handed out via DHCP).

I know that it would be better to simply prevent them from changing it but with students coming in with their own laptops, etc, this is often a problem. I only have a single classroom with about 20 students so once I know the IP (that is duplicate) and preferably the hostname, I can take the necessary steps.

Emailing the script is ideal because I can get it when I am out of the classroom and on my mobile.

Thanks, hope someone can help me out with this.

Comment: This could be a good question to ask [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Good DHCP servers ping any address they're about to Offer, as an attempt to make sure they're free before Offering them. So you could possibly set up something to watch your DHCP server logs.

Comment: Thats a good idea @ Spiff, I could grep the NACKs and send them to an email address for review. Thanks!